# Make a query to combine one result from two different tables with same / different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make single query for a single result from two different tables. This table has same columns and also different columns.

Table Deposits

| Name | D_Currency | D_Amount | Datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | USD | 500 | 2022-12-10 09:12:45 |
| Susan | JPY | 10000 | 2022-12-15 12:34:11 |
| John | KRW | 7000 | 2022-12-13 15:21:08 |

Table Withdrawal

| Name | W_Currency | W_Amount | Datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | USD | 500 | 2022-12-11 09:55:32 |
| Susan | EUR | 800 | 2022-12-17 11:23:45 |
| John | USD | 300 | 2022-12-13 13:33:43 |

Result I want:

| Name | D_Currency | D_Amount | W_Currency | W_Amount | Datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | USD | 500 |  |  | 2022-12-10 09:12:45 |
| Michael |  |  | USD | 500 | 2022-12-11 09:55:32 |
| John |  |  | USD | 300 | 2022-12-13 13:33:43 |
| John | KRW | 7000 |  |  | 2022-12-13 15:21:08 |
| Susan | JPY | 10000 |  |  | 2022-12-15 12:34:11 |
| Susan |  |  | EUR | 800 | 2022-12-17 11:23:45 |

I want all the columns from both tables, but the order is in Datetime.
I think I can use column Name for join, but not sure how to add Datetime.

First I tried join, which didn't work:

```
SELECT d.Name, d.D_currency, d.D_amount, w.W_currency, w.W_amount, 
d.Datetime as date, w.Datetime as date
FROM Deposits d
JOIN Withdrawal w on w.Name = d.Name
ORDER BY date
```

I was thinking of `UNION`, but don't have the slightest idea how to even use it.

Please help.

Comment: You need to `union` not `join`

Comment: Your idea to use UNION is correct. Select NULL as W_Currency and W_Amount in your first query and NULL for  D_Currency and D_Amount in your second query, then you just need to add a good ORDER BY clause.

Comment: search for mysql union different number of columns

Comment: `SELECT d.Name, d.D_Currency, d.D_Amount, w.W_Currency, w.W_Amount, d.Datetime
FROM Deposits d
JOIN Withdrawal w on w.Name = d.Name
UNION
SELECT w.Name, d.D_Currency, d.D_Amount, w.W_Currency, w.W_Amount, w.Datetime
FROM Deposits d
JOIN Withdrawal w on w.Name = d.Name
ORDER BY Datetime
`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) operation, the requirement is that you need to have the exact same schema for the two tables you're applying it on. You can use the NULL values to fill the fields whose value you don't have, and rename the field with the corresponding field name you have in the expected output table.

```
SELECT Name, D_Currency, D_Amount, 
             NULL AS W_Currency, NULL AS W_Amount,
       Datetime_ 
FROM Deposits
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, NULL AS D_Currency, NULL AS D_Amount, 
             W_Currency, W_Amount,
       Datetime_ 
FROM Withdrawal
ORDER BY Name
```

Some remarks to take into account when applying a union operation:

- Applying the union between two sets as we know it, is carried out by the `UNION ALL` operation. The difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL` is that the former applies an aggregation to eliminate the duplicates too, if you have any. Since in your case you're not supposed to have duplicates, you can avoid stacking up an unnecessary operation.
- The order of the fields over the two table you're carrying the union on is important. If the two tables don't have the same fields in the same order, the DBMS will throw a schema mismatch error.
- The last `ORDER BY` clause will apply on the whole output of the union operation.

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ZVqaB6afMyLT21ivBpcWD/0).